# Use CKEditor with CKfinder and save content to the database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a textarea which is a Ckeditor however I included the ckfinder which allows me upload images.
I need to send all the data inside the textarea to a page to process the data received.

Actually I can't send the data which is inside of the textarea.

```
      <label>Corpo da Instrução de Trabalho</label>
      <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Escrever o conteúdo da IT aqui...">

      </textarea>

      <script>

      // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
      // instance, using default configuration.

     // CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

     var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
     CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor );

   </script>
```

When I try to save the data on the file which receive the data I do something like this:

```
$myText = $_POST['editor1'];
```

But it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to submit it along with a form. And to include ckeditor.js file in the head tag: example:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>Classic editor replacing a textarea</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="savetextarea.php" method="post" >

    <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
    </textarea>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>

    <script>
        // CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor );
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

create **savetextarea.php** in the same folder and don't forget to print out the content:

```
<?php

$my_text = $_POST['editor1'];
print_r($my_text);
```

When you refresh the page add some image from [example](http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg) :-) and add some text, when you submit it it will show the content on your `savetextarea.php`

Comment: I already have done what you said. But on my savetextarea.php the $_PosT[''editor1'] just doesn't exist.

Comment: You mean it won't show up in your savetextarea.php? Try the example I posted in separate file, it works. Go line by line and compare with your code. Check if the CK library is included, and on savetextarea.php you need to show ckeditor. Are you submitting your form on the same page? Start from simple things without CKeditor. Just try simple php form, and see if you have any output. If you have, then it's ok you can move to ckeditor implementation. If you have complete example send me through http://pastebin.com and share here I'll fix it